# Heroku image not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Just pushed a latest version of my Rails 4 app to Heroku which included a number of new images. All but one of the images has updated. The old images were overwritten with the new ones and hence have the same names.

I've tried wiping cache locally, wiping cache on Heroku, closing browser etc but nothing seems to work.

It works locally no problem.

Anyone have any suggestions to "force" all images to update?

Comment: Are you using HTTP caching at all?

Comment: That's actually a separate thing from HTTP caching, but I think that answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

Had simmiliar problem,  using the following fixed the problem.
After logging onto Heroku

```
heroku run rake assets:clean
```

before pushing code to Heroku

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
```

I was working on a couple of things at the time but my best understanding of how I got images to Heroku was as per above

Pierre

Comment: would this explain why only 1 image has not updated?

Comment: i get an error when running the second part: `rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter`

Comment: 1- In my config/database.yml I have the following     development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: di_development
  pool: 5
  username: davidlee
  password:
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: di_test
  pool: 5
  username: davidlee
  password:
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: di_production
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password:

Comment: Tommy456 - 1/can't comment on first question 2/ Getting an error running the second part could be part of the problem - Do have the standard config files for Rails 4.  I updated from rails 3.2 and so had to use updated versions for Congig/application and also Config/envoronments(dev, prod, test)